# Borderlands Handsome Collection tag problem

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently came across this question that concerns the Borderlands Handsome Collection:

[I have all DLC and I can't level up past 50](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288332/i-have-all-dlc-and-i-cant-level-up-past-50)

The Handsome Collection is a collection of Borderland games, re-released on the next-gen console (PS4, Xbox One).  The question details a problem with Borderlands 2, which is part of the collection.

At the moment the question is tagged as [borderlands-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2).  However, it appears that this version of the game may be different to that of the original Borderlands 2 game.  We usually create additional tags for such questions (e.g. special edition, hd etc suffix tags).

How should we tag such questions?

Possible options:

- [borderlands-hc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-hc), tag by collection
- [borderlands-2-hc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2-hc), identify the question to its specific version
- [borderlands-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2), just re-use existing tags
- [borderlands-hc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-hc) and [borderlands-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2), tag by collection + generic version

I see other games following this new collection re-release format (Dead Rising, Bioshock etc).  I'm not sure if this is the same as with the Halo Master Chief Collection, or if the pending Batman collection is of the same format.

Comment: I don't see a problem with using the borderlands-hc tag, in addition to the game in question. It might help make things more specific.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf - We usually have version-specific tags, such as [tag:age-of-empires-2] and [tag:age-of-empires-2-hd].  A question will be tagged with one or the other.  For example, if specific to the hd release the question will just have the hd tag.

Comment: True, and that makes sense. But considering the Handsome Collection includes multiple games, it probably isn't a bad idea to tag a question as "borderlands-hc" and "borderlands-2"